# How to make bytea selection faster

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Currently my following query requires `5-6 seconds` to execute. This table has around `2.4 million` records. Each row having 7 `bytea` columns and summation of 7 columns are `80 KB` in size.

```
select * from test_table where id > 1 and id < 300;
```

Below is the postgresql configuration:

```
psql version: 9.3.1
shared_buffers = 3072MB
temp_buffers = 128MB
work_mem = 128MB
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
```

Machine info:

```
CPU: 2.30GHz
Core: 2
RAM : 10 GB
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the sql returns:

```
"Index Scan using test_table_pkey on test_table  (cost=0.43..24.47 rows=302 width=239) (actual time=0.037..0.847 rows=298 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: ((id > 1) AND (id < 300))"
"Total runtime: 1.438 ms"
```

Is it a normal behavior? Or is there something that I can modify to make the query a little bit faster?

Comment: Normal?  Maybe.  Slow? Definitely :).  Can you post the output of [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-explain.html)?  Also, do you have autovacuum running and/or recently executed `VACUUM ANALYZE` on that table?

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` will give more details about query execution. Can you give use this results?

Comment: @fvu yes the `autovacuum` is running. Also i ran it manually several times. I have added the `Explain Analize` result.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I have updated the question and added the `Explain Analyze` result.

Comment: @SabujHassan There are results of simple `EXPLAIN`. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` gives more information about query execution statistics.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I have updated my question with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result.

Comment: Your query only needs one and half milliseconds to be run on the **server** (`Total runtime: 1.438 ms`) The 5-6 seconds that *you* see are caused by transferring the data from the server **to the client**.

Comment: @SabujHassan It looks like almost all delay is caused by the transfer of the result to the client computer, plus probably the time needed by whatever code receives these data to make them available in variables.  Can you share the relevant part of theprogram with us?

Comment: From `pgAdmin` I can see the execution time at the left-botton on the panel. I thought it shows the execution time there. I have then redirected the output into a file, and still asking for same time. By the way, I am using `Java/JPA` to fetch the records and from my application its even taking around 5-6 seconds. I am basically stuck here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried with redirecting the output into a file and executed the sql from my server's `psql` console. Its still taking same amount of time.

Comment: You are sending ~23MB from the server process to the client process and then writing those 23MB to a file. Plus the `bytea` is sent as hex-encoded string value which means that it sends much more than just 23MB over the wire (and the processing of the data in JDBC/JPA has an additional overhead)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes you are right. Its the issue of transfer probably. I have checked the file and the size was big. Can you please post this as answer?

Comment: @SabujHassan You might be able to get somewhat faster transfers by using binary mode in the protocol. Availability of that depends on the client driver you are using. It's supported by PgJDBC. See the documentation.